# File of X,Y,Z coordinates and need to sort them low to high. I can read the file, allocate memory and assigned them to the structure,

Tags: c

Keep getting memory access violation on the first if statement. I can load the data from the file and tag to the structure.

```
typedef struct
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
} Coordinates;

typedef Coordinates * xyz;
int compare(const void *p1, const void *p2)
{
    const xyz point1 = *(const xyz *)p1;
    const xyz point2 = *(const xyz *)p2;
    if (point1->x < point2->x)  return -1;    //read access violation
    if (point1->x > point2->x)  return 1;
    if (point1->y < point2->y)  return -1;
    if (point1->y > point2->y)  return 1;
    if (point1->z < point2->z)  return -1;
    if (point1->z > point2->z)  return 1;
    else return 0;
 }

int main()
{
    int numberofpoints;
    //allocates memory
    Coordinates * xyz = (Coordinates *)malloc(sizeof(Coordinates)*numberofpoints);
    //call qsort
    qsort(xyz, numberofpoints, sizeof(xyz), compare);
}
```

Comment: Pleae make a [mre]. I know it might be hard, but it is necessary. Consider hardcoding and intialising an array. If that does not work include your input reading. I.e. prove that you "can load the data from the file and tag to the structure".

Comment: `xyz` is a pointer to `Coordinates`.  So here you are casting to a pointer to pointer to Coordinates `(const xyz *)p1;`. But semantically I think it is a pointer to Coordinates, because you array contains Coordinates. Please explain.

Comment: You are using `xyz` as a typename AND as a variable name. That is risky. At least for making answer easier use different identifiers.

Comment: You are defining a pointer type with typedef. That is risky and is an obstacle for answering your question. I recommend to change that.

Comment: Dont typedef pointer! It's confusing and lead to many errors. So start by deleting the line `typedef Coordinates * xyz;` and then fix the compile errors/warnings

Comment: Hi USCCT. May I recommend to change the title? At least remove the explanation part. But actually I would recommend to change it to "Segfault with qsort and typedefed pointer type." Knowing the answer, that makes your question easier to find and in my opinion really useful. If you then make a MRE it turns into something very upvoteable.

Comment: Please make an [mre], for a detailed answer it is necessary to know whether you are handling an array of `Coordinates` or an array of pointer to `Coordinates`.

Answer (score 1):

The error is here:

```
const xyz point1 = *(const xyz *)p1;
const xyz point2 = *(const xyz *)p2;
                   ^       ^^^
                   |       wrong type
                   |
                  wrong dereference
```

Simply do

```
const  Coordinates * point1 = (const  Coordinates *)p1;
const  Coordinates * point2 = (const  Coordinates *)p2;
```

And avoid typedef of pointers. It's confusing and error prone.

So delete this:

```
typedef Coordinates * xyz;
```

If you really, really want pointer typedef, you should at least use a meaningful name, i.e.

```
typedef Coordinates * CoordinatesPtr;
```

Further you need to change `sizeof(xyz)` to `sizeof *xyz`

Comment: Beat me to it... May I recommend to explain how NOT defining a pointer type would have prevented the error? Becaue then I could add it to my dupe lib as "Why not define a pointer type?".

Answer (score 0):

`qsort` requires the size of the element in the third parameter. You are giving the size of the pointer.

Change it to

```
 qsort(xyz, numberofpoints, sizeof(Coordinates), compare);
```